# Pseudo-possession or marginal possession

Tags: reference-request, possession

I'm looking for material on this topic but always seem to fail to find something, and that's probably because the terms, although kind of accepted, seem to be too vague.

By these terms I refer to when languages express possession of abstract concepts that cannot possibly be possessed in a literal way: **feelings** (*it.* Ho paura = I'm scared), **pain** (I have an headache), **needs** (*it.* Ho fame = I'm hungry), and so on.

Are you aware of materials that list occurrences and or examples on this, specifically for English? I'm aware of an article written by Paolo Ramat, Gianguido Manzelli and Elisa Roma, "*Remarks on marginal possession: are feelings owned?*" from *Mediterranean Languages*, but that's about it.

Please note that I'm referring to examples in English (or Italian, if you know any) where someone can express possession of something abstract/impossible to possess by using the verb **to have**. So expressing a possession that sounds literal but is not, such as *I have an headache*, since I do not really possess the headache.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. In languages with non trivial possession systems there could be different possessive markers for abstract 'possessions', but that's not the case with English. So what then?

Comment: Subjects of gerunds can "possess" them with the possessive marker. Originators or discoverers can "possess" what they possessed or discovered: Newton's Law, Alzheimer's Disease. Gods know how many governed uses there are of the preposition _of_ and possessive nouns.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, have you looked at [Metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf)? This is normal behavior, and you'll find many examples in [Lakoff and Johnson](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/L&J-Lg-Review.pdf), for instance.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough, I'll add something to clarify. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, you're limiting this to the verb _have_ plus a metaphorical object, right? Then the question is figuring out what the metaphor theme is. To start with, one ***has*** a human body, so one also _has_ every part of one's body, and everything it grasps or contains. Since most metaphors are ultimately projections of human body parts and behavioral traits -- like _having a firm handle on calculus_, for instance -- this licenses possession of various sorts, including _have_, with practically any abstract noun phrase. Provided it's coherent with a metaphor theme.

Comment: @jlawler Yes, but limiting it to a certain kind of expression. Things like toothache, headache, that you say you "have" in English. For example, in Italian we "have" fear, hunger, thirst, and so on, which are no physical traits that you possess, but things that don't even materially exist except as concepts, still you "have" them. If I find the article aforementioned I'll link to it.

Comment: We also "have" abstract concepts -- they're in our brains, right, like emotions and memories and stories. The point is that they're **metaphors**. Any abstraction is a metaphor; your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to figure out the metaphor theme involved.

Comment: The phenonenom normally called 'possession' is semantically heterogeneous. It almost always includes meronomy, and often other things too. Arguably physical possessions are actually the minority.

Comment: I think the OP should phrase his question in the form of a question in order to clarify it.   I also think that the semantics of possessive forms and verbs meaning "have" could fill one or more books.  For this reason, I'm voting to close, but not without the hope that the OP will ask a new, clearer question.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann What exactly is not clear? I'm not asking about all of the forms to express possession, but about one. All of the examples (which are going to be a small number) where you express possession of an emotional state (I have fear), a pain (I have an headache), so things that cannot be literally possessed. I don't think that's very complex and/or broad.

Comment: @Alenanno:   What's unclear is the question, which isn't even in the form of a sentence.   What's broad and complex is the semantics of the word "have" and of other possessive constructions.  "I have a headache."  "I have relatives."  "I have the heebie jeebies."  "I have short toes."  "I have three options."  "I have a vision for a big new building." "I have a wallet, but it isn't mine."  "I have a certain je ne sais quoi."  "The story doesn't have an ending."  "I have fame!"   Do any of these occurrence of "have" express the same concept?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann That's more what I'm talking about. Some of those are literal possessions (You have a wallet, a real object, even if it isn't yours) but others express possession of something that cannot be actually possessed. You don't really possess a vision, it's an idea in your head, and we say we "have" it. In my question, I was referring to these last things, not "vision" but feelings, pains, needs that we usually say we "possess" in common language. I don't really know how else to explain it. I don't think there are many examples of it.

Comment: @curiousdannii they might be the minority, but I can't find material about any non-physical possession.